# opencv mat 2d array, swap index and value

Tags: opencv

I have a 2d Mat which has x,y as indexes and data is a z value.

I would like to create a mat with x,z index
and give y values as the data.

Yes, I understand I would have to limit the range and datatype of z.

I can do it element by element.  Is there something faster?

```
sample
 array in:
               Y |                (X,Y) = Z
               3 | 3  1  3
               2 | 1  3  4
               1 | 2  2  1
                 ----------  X
                   1  2  3

array out:     Z |
               4 | 0  0  2         (X,Z) = Y
               3 | 3  2  3
               2 | 1  1  0
               1 | 2  3  1
                 --------------
                   1  2  3  X
```

The resulting matrix will actually be very sparse.
The original will be roughly 100x20  (x100,y20).
The result will be probably 100x1000 with the 20 y values
in each x column.  So that is pretty sparse!
I don't know if that matters in the selection of available tools.

Comment: please post some code, with a sample input mat, and the desired output. You'll probably also figure also that what you're trying doesn't make much sense

Comment: Added an example